# Serialization of NodaTime Instant does not work with Asp.Net Core web api and OData

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, odata, nodatime

I am using NodaTime as DateTime-API in my AspNetCore OData - webapp. Everything works as expected until serialization. This is my entityBase.

```
public class DbEntity
{
    public Instant CreateDate { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my Startup-ConfigureServices Method:

```
services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
    .AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ConfigureForNodaTime(DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb));
services.AddDbContext<DefaultContext>(
    options => options
        .UseLazyLoadingProxies()
        .UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("someString"), o => o.UseNodaTime()));
services.AddTransient<ICrudEditable, CrudEditable>();
services.AddOData();
```

I am using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData 7.0.1` `NodaTime 2.4.0` Version together with `NodaTime.Serialization.JsonNet 2.0.0` and `Newtonsoft.Json 11.0.2`.

Actions:

```
// GET api/values
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Get ( )
{
    return Ok(new DbEntity { CreateDate = SystemClock.Instance.GetCurrentInstant() });
}
```

Everything fine so far. It´s an action from the default Values controller (derived from `ControllerBase`). But if I call below action, where Controller derives from ODataController, CreateDate is empty:

```
[EnableQuery]
[ODataRoute("entity")]
public IActionResult Get()
{
    return Ok(new DbEntity { CreateDate = SystemClock.Instance.GetCurrentInstant() });
}
```

No error, no nothing, just empty..

**EDIT**
I´ve raised an issue on github, for anyone interested on that issue: https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/1626

Comment: I'll see if I can reproduce this... out of interest, is there any reason you're fetching the contract resolver but not doing anything with it?

Comment: I've just tried to reproduce, and *without* the call to AddJsonOptions, it returns an empty value - *with* the call, it returns expected JSON. The resolver bit isn't necessary though: just `.AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ConfigureForNodaTime(DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb))` works fine. Sample result: `{"modfiedDate":"2018-09-19T05:33:47.1391681Z","modifyUser":"d1b690ad-baf6-4045-819b-0c88b8db6d57","version":10,"createDate":"2018-09-19T00:33:47.1391681Z","createUser":"a8fd0ebf-4514-44de-a45c-300fd44ee905","deleted":false}`.

Comment: That's using netcoreapp2.1 and just the Microsoft.AspNetCore.App package, with no version... (Literally just "create ASP.NET Core app", pick "API".)

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks for looking at this. I´ve used the resolver before but forgot to remove this line.. I´ll remove it from the question too..
If I paste in your AddJsonOptions call it doesn´t work either..

Comment: I´ve made an edit to the question and added the complete ConfigureServices Method.. Maybe there is my fault..?

Comment: If I reproduce it the same way (new WebApi ... ) everything works.. Trying to find out what I have lost on the way ;)

Comment: Just tried to call an Instant from a normal AspNet Controller in the same project, it works.. It seems like there is something going wrong when odata comes into play.. I´ll edit the question again

Comment: Unfortunately I know nothing about OData Web APIs. I wonder whether they use separate Json.NET configuration.

Comment: Ok. Maybe there is someone else who can help me with this one. But thank you very much anyway! I know now where the error comes from, so step 1 is done ;)

Comment: @Joshit did you ever solve this?

Comment: @Snæbjørn no. I´ve finally decided to get rid of odata, as I wanted to go with .net core.

Comment: Similar issue for me... @JonSkeet is there any chance that Noda will get support for OData?

Comment: @OldShaterhan: It's not something Noda Time would support within its core - I'd be happy to help someone else create an integration package, but it's not something I'd be doing myself.

Comment: @JonSkeet I see, thanks.

Comment: Has anyone solved this issue? I have to drop NodaTime from my projects. Please help me if someone has solved it or has solution for this issue

Comment: I have created a serializer but I am getting one issue with my custom serializer. Please help me resolve serializer https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/1626#issuecomment-1121977734